# SQL Server February exceeded to march

Tags: sql-server

I have problem in regards with the February dates:

The result is this:

```
PAYPERIOD
--------------
02/15/2017
03/02/2017
```

Expected result should be like this:

```
PAYPERIOD
--------------
02/15/2017
02/28/2017
```

My code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Get15thDayPayPeriod]
            @MinDate AS DATE = NULL,
            @MaxDate AS DATE = NULL
AS
-- Execute sp:
-- EXEC [Get15thDayPayPeriod] @MinDate = '02/01/2017', @MaxDate = '02/28/2017'


-- DECLARE @MinDate DATE = CONVERT(VARCHAR(15),DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0), 101), 
-- @MaxDate DATE = CONVERT(VARCHAR(15),EOMONTH(GETDATE()),101),
-- @MinDate DATE = '20170901', 
-- @MaxDate DATE = '20170930',
DECLARE @date DATE; 
DECLARE @counter INT = 0;


IF ISNULL(@MinDate, 0) = 0
BEGIN
    SET @MinDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(15),DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0), 101)
END

IF ISNULL(@MaxDate, 0) = 0 
BEGIN
    SET @MaxDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(15),EOMONTH(GETDATE()),101)
END

DECLARE my_cursor CURSOR LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY FOR 
  SELECT TOP (Datediff(day, @MinDate, @MaxDate) + 1) Date = 
  Dateadd(day, Row_number() 
                 OVER( 
                   ORDER 
  BY a.object_id) - 1, @MinDate) 
  FROM   sys.all_objects a 
         CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects b; 
CREATE TABLE #temp (Biweekly varchar(15))
OPEN my_cursor 

FETCH next FROM my_cursor INTO @date 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
  BEGIN 
      IF( @counter = 15 ) 
        BEGIN
        --PRINT @date
        --PRINT @date -- here is where you get the 15th date
          IF DAY(@date) BETWEEN 10 AND 30
              BEGIN
                SET @date = DATEADD(DAY,(15-DATEPART(DAY,@date)),@date)
                INSERT INTO #temp values (CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), @date, 101))
                PRINT CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), @date, 101)
                SET @counter = 0
              END
              IF  @counter = 0 
              BEGIN
                    SET @date = DATEADD(DAY,(30-DATEPART(DAY,@date)),@date)
                    INSERT INTO #temp values (CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), @date, 101))
                    PRINT CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), @date, 101)
              END
        END 
      SET @counter = @counter + 1 
      FETCH next FROM my_cursor INTO @date 
  END 

CLOSE my_cursor 
DEALLOCATE my_cursor

SELECT PAYPERIOD = CASE WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, Biweekly) <> ('Saturday') AND DATENAME(WEEKDAY, Biweekly) <> ('Sunday')
                    THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), Biweekly, 101)
                    ELSE CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, Biweekly) <= 2
                        THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(15),DATEADD(DAY, -1 * (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, Biweekly) + 1), Biweekly), 101)
                        ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), DATEADD(DAY, DATEPART(WEEKDAY, Biweekly) * -1 + 6, Biweekly), 101)
                        END
                    END 
FROM #temp
DROP TABLE #temp

RETURN 0
```

Other dates works perfectly fine, the only problem is on month of February.

I tried adding condition inside `IF @counter = 0` but no luck...

Comment: is your date format MM/DD/YYYY?

Comment: A clear *spec* on what the requirements are here would greatly improve the question. At the moment, you're posting code that is clearly *broken* (if it weren't, you wouldn't be posting it here) and expecting us to *intuit* the purpose behind it.

Comment: @Tanner, that is correct.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, sorry about that, I'll work with that next time if I ask question.

Comment: are the 2 dates you posted what you pass in to the procedure? as min and max?

Comment: The very first problematic thing here on your code is that you are working with varchars instead of dates. Try to use date formats only, that only will certainly help a lot. Like Damien already said, it is almost impossible to us to understand your problem without knowing the requirements and not seeing any data. Try to pin down the problem first, add a [mcve] so we can actually help.

Comment: @Tanner, yep, it will be used as `@MinDate` is used for first day of the month and `@MaxDate` is used for the last day of the month.

Comment: @JorgeCampos, okay I'll try that suggestion.

Comment: also - `IF ISNULL(@MinDate, 0) = 0` this gives an error, comparing dates to int

Comment: and this doesn't seem like a good candidate for a cursor

Comment: @Tanner, So what do you suggest?

Comment: fix the question to properly detail you requirements instead of just posting some code. The code is not great and you haven't explained the logic of what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you be able to get what you need by using some date functions?

```
select distinct 
    MonthStart     = dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0,[Date] )  , 0)
  , Month15th      = dateadd(day,14,dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0,[Date] ), 0))
  , MonthEnd       = dateadd(day,-1,dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0,[Date] )+1, 0))
  --, MonthEndEom    = eoMonth(getdate()) /* sql server 2012+*/
from dates;
```

Using an adhoc dates table for this example:

```
declare @fromdate date = '20170101'
declare @thrudate date = '20171231'

;with n as (select n from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) t(n))
, dates as (
  select top (datediff(day, @fromdate, @thrudate)+1)
      [Date]=convert(date,dateadd(day,row_number() over(order by (select 1))-1,@fromdate))
  from n as deka cross join n as hecto cross join n as kilo 
                cross join n as tenK cross join n as hundredK
   order by [Date]
)

select distinct 
    MonthStart = dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0,[Date] )  , 0)
  , Month15th  = dateadd(day,14,dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0,[Date] ), 0))
  , MonthEnd   = dateadd(day,-1,dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0,[Date] )+1, 0))
  --, MonthEndEom    = eoMonth(getdate()) /* sql server 2012+*/
from dates;
```

For 2017, this returns:

```
+------------+------------+------------+
| MonthStart | Month15th  |  MonthEnd  |
+------------+------------+------------+
| 2017-01-01 | 2017-01-15 | 2017-01-31 |
| 2017-02-01 | 2017-02-15 | 2017-02-28 |
| 2017-03-01 | 2017-03-15 | 2017-03-31 |
| 2017-04-01 | 2017-04-15 | 2017-04-30 |
| 2017-05-01 | 2017-05-15 | 2017-05-31 |
| 2017-06-01 | 2017-06-15 | 2017-06-30 |
| 2017-07-01 | 2017-07-15 | 2017-07-31 |
| 2017-08-01 | 2017-08-15 | 2017-08-31 |
| 2017-09-01 | 2017-09-15 | 2017-09-30 |
| 2017-10-01 | 2017-10-15 | 2017-10-31 |
| 2017-11-01 | 2017-11-15 | 2017-11-30 |
| 2017-12-01 | 2017-12-15 | 2017-12-31 |
+------------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: Thanks!, I'm trying so hard to get this right and mine was so messy... thanks to you.

Comment: I have another problem, here is what I am trying to achieve here,
if 15th or the 30th day falls on weekends then it will be reverted to its closest friday of the week.  can you help me with it?